# python dictionary as a parameter with multiple values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, django-1.8

I'm newbie to python, started with python 3 and django1.8. Can we pass dictionary as a parameter with multiple values in it, but lesser the arguments in the function definition.

```
def save_myobj(request):
    '''
    '''
    reqobj = dict(zip(request.POST.keys(), request.POST.values()))
    my_dict = prepare_profile_dict(**reqobj)
    obj =  Model.objects.get(pk=1)
    obj.__dict__.update(my_dict)
    obj.save()
    return HttpResponse("true")
```

Here is my request object:

```
reqobj  = {
            u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': u'xzlrzJkpKb0aAIvdJ7Z7aX05uhHjnwjX',
            u'email': u'',
            u'first_name': u'abc',
            u'last_name': u'def',
            u'revenue': u''
          }
```

and here is `prepare_profile_dict`

```
def prepare_profile_dict(first_name, last_name, email):
    ''' '''
    return { 
            "revenue" : get_revenue(),
            "first_name":first_name, 
            "last_name":last_name, 
            "email":email
           };
```

But getting error,

```
TypeError at /profile/save/
prepare_profile_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'revenue'
```

I don't think there is anything to do with Model.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    '''
    '''
    first_name = models.TextField("first_name", blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    last_name  = models.TextField("last_name", blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    email  =  models.TextField("email", blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    revenue  = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: What does your model look like?

Comment: I assume that `prepare_my_dict` should be `prepare_profile_dict`?

Comment: You can if you change your `prepare_profile_dict` function to take a `**kwargs` parameter at the end.

Comment: You want to filter `my_dict` to contain only keys with the names of the *keyword parameters* of `prepare_profile_dict()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `prepare_profile_dict` doesn't accept a `revenue` argument (as stated in the error message); only `first_name`, `last_name` and `email`. Your dict expansion when calling the function, however, does contain the `revenue` keyword. Either remove it from `reqobj`:

```
del reqobj['revenue']
```

or add a `**kwargs` argument at the end of `prepare_profile_dict` to catch any extra keyword arguments (that will be ignored inside the function).

```
def prepare_profile_dict(first_name, last_name, email, **kwargs):
    ...
```

(Obviously, the same goes for `csrfmiddlewaretoken`.)

---

Also, you can use the querysets [`update`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update) method:

```
def save_myobj(request):
    reqobj = dict(zip(request.POST.keys(), request.POST.values()))
    my_dict = prepare_profile_dict(**reqobj)
    # ensure my_dict only contains relevant keys
    Model.objects.get(pk=1).update(**my_dict)
    # No .save method needed
    return HttpResponse("true")
```

Comment: Thank you. I can not vote but +1 for `.update(**reqobj)`. I didn't know that.

Comment: @Evert- In my case there will be only one object in the Model for now.but this line is not working 
`obj =  Model.objects.all()[:1].get().update(my_dict)` Getting error 
`AttributeError at /profile/save/
'Model' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: You don't need `Model.objects.all()[:1].get()`; that's overkill.

Comment: But the `.get()` method may not return a queryset; instead, try `Model.objects.filter(pk=1)`.update(**my_dict)`. `.filter()` should return a queryset (with one item), on which `.update()` should work.

Comment: I'd just whish to say that using a ModelForm would be the sane and safe thing to do here.

Answer (score 2):

The sane solution using a `ModelForm`:

```
# forms.py
from django import forms
from .models import Profile
from .somewhere import get_revenue

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"

   def clean_revenue(self):
       return get_revenue()

# views.py
from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import Profile

def save_myobj(request):
    if request.method !== "POST":
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(["POST"])

    profile = Profile.objects.get(pk=1)
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()         
        return HttpResponse("true")
    # returning form.errors might be better
    # but anyway:
    return HttpResponse("false")
```

Comment: @brunosdesthuilliers - Thanks!! `HttpResponseNotAllowed` is new for me. I'll check its doc for more details.